# Ошибка 404 в Symfony. Почему она появляется и как корректно её исправить?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, openserver

Простой учебный проект. Только начал изучать симфони. Сайт на OpenServer.
PHP 8.1.

Установил

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.2.*" my_project_directory
composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
composer require twig
composer require doctrine
composer require apache-pack
composer require symfony/asset
composer require maker
```

Перенес фреймворк из папки my_project_directory в корневую папку сайта.
Создал контроллер и вид для главной страницы. Работает.

Главная страница открывается в браузере по адресу http://symfony.local/public/

Вот код работающего контроллера (работают роуты любого вида - в аннотации, в ямеле, в комментарии).

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class PageController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'home_page')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('page/index.html.twig', [

        ]);
    }
}
```

Создал контроллер и вид для страницы категории. Не работает.

Страница открывается в браузере по адресу http://symfony.local/public/category и показывает ошибку 404 - Объект не найден! Запрашиваемый ресурс не найден.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class CategoryController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/category', name: 'add_category')]
    public function addCategory(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('category/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'CategoryController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

И так для любого контроллера. То есть работает только контроллер главной страницы. Остальные не работают. Файла .htaccess в папке public да и вообще во всем проекте нет.

Долго гуглил и нашел ответ.
Помогло

1. в корень сайта положить файл .htaccess с содержимым:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2. в папку public положить файл .htaccess с содержимым:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Работает. Открывает нужные страницы. Но не могу понять почему без них не работает, и зачем это надо делать руками.

Почему без этих файлов в symfony появляется ошибка 404 и как корректно её исправить? Я всё правильно сделал? Команд в файлах достаточно для дальнейшей работы ил скоро (например при работе с бд или ещё чем нибудь) снова придется что то править/добавлять?

Answer (score 0):

Как исправить 404 без дополнительных файлов в веб сервере. Очень просто - обращайтесь к фронт контроллеру (index.php в вашей версии) и у вас не будет 404.

Вам же веб сервер подсказывает - 404 не найден путь. По вашему что происходит когда вы заходите по адресу
`http://symfony.local/public/category`  ? А зайдите по адресу  `http://symfony.local/index.php/public/category` - получилось ? Точно получилось.

Теперь сопоставьте те правила которые вы прописали для веб сервера и вы придете к выводу что веб сервер вам отдает ровно то что вы у него спрашивали. Вы же должны запрашивать какой то php файл, верно ?  Ну и какой именно файл вы запрашивали в первом случае ?

Если до сих пор не понятно, напишите, я еще более подробно расскажу.

ps.

> Почему без этих файлов в symfony появляется ошибка 404 и как корректно её исправить?

это не файлы в symfony и к symfony отношения не имею ни малейшего. Этими файлами вы настраиваете веб сервер. Разберите чуть подробнее процесс взаимодействия вашего как пользователя (браузер) и php интерпретатора. Нет же ни какой магии, все подчиняется определенным правилам (протоколам) и определенной последовательности.